# [javascript]radio button jumps to first option

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a standard html from with a couple of radio buttons (3 of them actually).

With:

```
function abo_show() 
{
    var x = document.gms_option.gms_element1;
    console.log(x.value);
    if (x.value = "1") { 
        document.getElementById("abo").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("gms_abo1").style.display="table-row";
        document.getElementById("gms_abo2").style.display="table-row";
        document.getElementById("gms_abo3").style.display="table-row";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("abo").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("gms_abo1").style.display="table-row";
        document.getElementById("gms_abo2").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("gms_abo3").style.display="none";
    }
}
```

I try to show a couple of extra buttons, based on the first 3. The new ones are in a `div` "abo", that is hidden by default (in css: `"display:none"`).

But when I click on a radio button to select, it executes and jumps to option 1.

No idea why. Could someone explain and help?

Comment: can you make us an example at jsfiddle please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x.value = "1"` because of this.

you use a single `=` doing an assignment not a comparison. This causes the if to always succeed. just  use `==` or even `===`instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have an easy = in an if statement. Its not compared, it is set.
Your code sets x.value to "1" instead of comparing it.
Use:

```
if(x.value=="1") {
```